# jQuery change css right align when td data numeric (dynamic table)

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

```
$('tr > td:gt(0)').filter(function() {
                        return this.innerHTML.match(/^[0-9\s\.,]+$/);
                        }).css('text-align','right');
```

I am trying to loop through a dynamic table and right align every td that contains numeric data on each row EXCEPT the first td on each row.

It works on the first tr but not each subsequent row...

Comment: On behalf of user2374907: Does this work? `$('tr > td').each(function() {
 if(!$(this).is(':first') && $(this).innerHTML.match(/^[0-9\s\.,]+$/) {
  $(this).css('text-align','right');
}
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is that your jQuery selector is collecting all `td` elements (that are children of `tr`s), and *then* sub-selecting all but the first one. To avoid this, you can iterate over the rows of the table, applying your filter to the `td` elements of each one:

```
$('tr').each( function () { 
    $(this).children('td:gt(0)').filter(function() {
        return this.innerHTML.match(/^[0-9\s\.,]+$/);
    }).css('text-align','right')
});
```

If you only want to apply this to a certain table, change the selector in the first line to `'#table-id tr'`.

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/munderwood/d48Q4/1/

Comment: Works like a charm and your explanation makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: As a follow up, how would I subsequently move the corresponding <th> in the <thead> row to the right too. Of course, the <th> is a text label so it doesn't meet the regex. Thanks in advance.

Comment: fails with negative values